# Install font for specific language

Tags: fonts, language-support

I'm using Ubuntu in English. I also use Arabic to name files and folders. How can I install a default font for specific Arabic and another for English ?

Comment: You can't, Only one font as default. It is better to look for a font with nice look for both.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running the command:

```
gnome-language-selector
```

Comment: language selector to change the language. I want just to choose a specific font for Arabic language while keeping the system in English with its proper fonts.